# Just here to say hi!

Tags: blockchain

I just found this video today and its extremely helpful. I might run into problems later on so I hope to receive help from this forum. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange and happy to hear you're interested! Since we try to keep this forum as focused as possible, your question will be closed. Don't see this as a discouragement from asking further questions, this is just how these forums generally work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this because it's not a question.

Answer (score 2):

Nice to have you Omkar!!
Please,  do feel welcome.

I am sad to see somebody already downvoted you, so I felt obliged to throw in a word of encouragement. Rest assured, we are a tight community and always welcome newcomers.

Feel free to ask anything, there are no "wrong" questions. It might take some time for you to get a hang of the forum rules, but we all started from somewhere.